# Confluence Search by Excluding a Label

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

My company uses Confluence for our documentation, and one of the suggestions was to label a section of Archived documents; and then be able to search by excluding that label.

There seems to be no way that I've found to do that so far, I can label things, but it seems the Confluence itself does not allow for the exclusion of a label when searching.  I tried to use the NOT command, with no luck.

Does anyone have a macro or any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I looked into the problem and found out that CQL has a confusing syntax and was not able to figure out answer easily. 
To exclude label you just need to put minus sign before the label.
Example -
[image]

Comment: Where did you even find that? I searched for a few hours looking everywhere I thought I could!  Thank you!

Comment: No problem, also could you mark the answer as right.